# Error reading request body that contains a pdf in an Azure Function

Tags: c#, http, blob, azure-functions

I had an azure function with blob trigger that I wanted to use in a Logic app. Then I realized that only HTTP trigger azure functions are supported in Logic apps.

I migrated the code that was working fine in the blob triggered function to a new http triggered azure function. I replaced the stream received in the blob triggered function for the request body in the http triggered one, but I wasn't able to open the pdf created with that stream.

**Blob trigger Function**

```
public static void Run([BlobTrigger("attachments/{name}", Connection = "")]Stream blobPdf, string name, ILogger log)
{
    // Create MemoryStream
    var streamPdf = new MemoryStream();
    CopyStream(blobPdf, streamPdf);
    // Create PDF from MemoryStream
    var pdf = PdfReader.Open(streamPdf);
}
```

**HTTP trigger Function**

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
        // Create MemoryStream
        var streamPdf = new MemoryStream();
        CopyStream(req.Body, streamPdf);
        // Create PDF from MemoryStream
        var pdf = PdfReader.Open(streamPdf);
}
```

The error pops when it tries to open the pdf in last line.
There's 2 errors depending on the pdf file. The first one is:

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: ExtractTextFromPDF. PdfSharp: Invalid PDF file: no trailer found.
```

The second one is:

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: ExtractTextFromPDF. PdfSharp: Unexpected token 'n' in PDF stream. The file may be corrupted. If you think this is a bug in PDFsharp, please send us your PDF file.
```

Comment: Can you please check what is the Content-Type in invoked HttpRequest? Also, HttpRequest's Content can be read as stream by `ReadAsStreamAsync` method.

Comment: `HttpRequest req` content-type is `multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------705129497655751336546472`

Comment: Also, I can't use `ReadAsStreamAsync`. Do I need a library or something?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: @XaviAndreu post the error message as well

Comment: @silent updated the question with the errors.

Comment: @HariHaran updated the question with the errors

Comment: Looks like an error in the way you submit your pdf (assuming that the file is a valid pdf - have you checked that?!). How are you testing your function? Postman etc?

Comment: I tried different pdf files, some created by me, some downloaded. Yes, I'm using postman -> Post -> Body -> form-data -> file -> submit a pdf file

Comment: Actually tried binary instead of form-data and it worked. Thank you for pointing out that the error might be in the way I was submitting it. Will post an answer once I have it all done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the way to submit the pdf in Postman. `Binary` instead of `form-data` solved the problem.